# All events stop responding when I change title of toolbar

Tags: events, toolbar, sencha-touch, carousel

I have a Panel that has a Toolbar and a Carousel (with several cards created dynamically)

I created an event that is fired in every cardswitch, here is the code:

```
var myCarousel = [{
            xtype: 'carousel',
              cls: 'card',
              listeners: {
                    cardswitch: function(container, newCard, oldCard, index){

                    //Here goes code of the event
                }
            },
            items: cards 
}];
```

if inside the cardswitch function I change the title of my toolbar, all the events stop working, I cannot change cards or go inside the content of the card when I click.

I have tried firing an alert inside the cardswitch and the app keeps working normally and the alert gets displayed just fine, but when I change the toolbar button the issue arises, so I guess the cardswitch function is not the problem.  Should I do something else after updating the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed:

Solved by adding the toolbar as a dockeditem of the carousel, instead of having it as a dockeditem in the container that contains the carousel.

Like this:

```
      this.myCarousel = [{
            xtype: 'carousel',
              cls: 'card',
              listeners: {
                    cardswitch: function(container, newCard, oldCard, index){
                    this.dockedItems.items[0].setTitle(newCard.myName);
                }
            },
            items: cards,
            dockedItems: [{
                 xtype: 'toolbar',
                 dock: 'top',
                 title: "A title",
                 items: []
            }]
}];
```

So now when I swipe, I get "myName" set to the title of the toolbar